# Filling dataframe with True values based on criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created a dataframe with columns as different documents and rows as features of these documents like this:
[image]

There are many more documents and ~70 more features. I want to replace the NaN values with True or leave as NaN depending on whether the document contains the feature (row).

Suppose:

```
t1_list = ['date', 'review_score']
```

Then, the first two rows under t1 in the dataframe would appear as True and course_id and the rest of the rows would remain NaN by checking the elements of `t1_list` against the current row.
Each "document" has a corresponding list similar to what is listed above containing the features of that document. I am essentially just creating a large matrix with True/NaN values to easily see which documents contain or do not contain the same features. So, if the current row name is contained in the respective list replace NaN with True.

Comment: I get what you're asking in a round about way.  But you'll need to be more specific.  Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: For whatever it's worth, many (most?) analyses are structured with the idea that your unit of observation (a document) would be in the rows, and an attribute of that unit (a document feature) would be in the columns.

Comment: @BrendanCox This is the way it was requested to be done

Comment: Your documents are stored in an arbitrary number of variables? Your life might be easier if you instead store them in a dict: `d = {'t1: ['date', 'review_score'], 't2': ...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose you have a dict like this one

```
features_per_doc = {"t1": ['date', 'review_score'], "t2": ['review_score'],\
                     "t3":['review_score', 'date', 'review_score']}
```

then you can do:

```
df.apply(lambda column: column.index.isin(features_per_doc[column.name]))
```

this will return:

```
                 t1     t2     t3
date           True  False   True
review_score   True   True   True
course_id     False  False  False
```

and if you want to get rid of the Falses then you can do

```
df.replace(False, pd.np.nan)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your dataframe is `df` with columns as document names and index as features. Put your documents under a dictionary to better access them. Lets say this `dict` is `docDict` with keys as document name i.e. t1, t2, and so on and content as the document content. Then the following code should work. If you dont want to use `dict` then you will have to traverse every document in some other fashion but rest will be same.

```
for doc in df.columns:
    for feature in docDict[doc]:
        df[feature][doc] = True
```

Now your dataframe `df` will have required results.